Troubleshoot nftables configuration for ssh
I can connect via ssh to my cloud server. In consequence of the rule-set below the server refused ssh connection.
I don't use custom ssh port. The server has an IPv6 address, in case that matters. And I get the same result if I apply this rule-set.
flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        tcp dport 22 accept
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
    }
}


In conclusion: iP6 matters the following rule-set works:
flush ruleset                                                                    
                                                                                 
table inet firewall {
                                                                                 
    chain inbound_ipv4 {
        # icmp type echo-request limit rate 5/second accept      
    }

    chain inbound_ipv6 {                                                         
        # accept neighbour discovery otherwise connectivity breaks
        icmpv6 type { nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
    }

    chain inbound {                                                              
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop } 
        iifname lo accept
        meta protocol vmap { ip : jump inbound_ipv4, ip6 : jump inbound_ipv6 }
        tcp dport { 22} accept
    }                                                                            
                                                                                 
    chain forward {                                                              
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;                        
    }                                                                            
}


For domain lookups you'll obviously need port 53 in the mix. Or use hardcoded IPs in the sources.list instead of names.

Typically UDP or TCP is implementation dependent, the general recommendation for firewalls is to allow both protocols both ways. @Hölderlin  And I guess that should be a dport of 53 ...

@Hölderlin ...  that needs to be dport 53 on outgoing, sport 53 on incoming.
